# Ruby on Rails: proper way to return data from methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, standards

How do I follow OOP standards within RoR controllers?

The setup:  submitting data to a form & then manipulating it for display.  This is a simplified example.

```
app/controllers/discounts_controller.rb  
...  
def show  
  @discount = Discount.find(params[:id])  
  formatted = calc_discounts(@discount)  
end  
...  

private  
  calc_discounts    
    half_off = @discount.orig_price * .5  
    quarter_off = @discount.orig_price * .25  
    return {:half => half_off, :quarter => quarter_off}  
  end  
...
```

Or is it better to place this in a library with `attr_accessor` and then create new instances of the library class within the controller? Or is there an even better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you want to return that hash as a JSON response?

Comment: Also, I don't think the code above works.. @discount is an object of the Discount class, and you're multiplying it by .5 and .25?

Comment: The hash needs to be used in html output.  Can be strings.  Question updated - `@discount` changed to `@discount.orig_price`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question to ask yourself is "is this logic useful for the view, model, or both?"

If the answer is that it's only useful for display purposes, I would put that logic in a view helper. If it's also beneficial to the model, put it there. Maybe something like this:

```
class Discount
  def options
    {half: (self.orig_price * .5), quarter: (self.orig_price * .25)}   
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you can just locate the record in question:

```
def show  
  @discount = Discount.find(params[:id])  
end
```

And display it in the view:

```
<h1>half: <%= @discount.options[:half] %> </h1>
<h1>quarter: <%= @discount.options[:quarter] %> </h1>
```

Comment: If display only, put in view helper.  If needed by display & model, put in model helper.  But either way, never in the controller itself?

Comment: @ci, yep - the idea is to keep logic outside your controllers as much as possible and only use them to link your view to your model.  As an aside, it's generally bad style to use return unnecessarily.  Github has an excellent style guide that I would recommend - https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

Comment: @Josh What would be the point of declaring a local variable `formatted` inside of your controller like that?

Comment: @RobW. no point, it was just a copy/paste of what was already there.  I edited it to be more clear that you can simply access that data from the view.

Comment: Good edit, I didn't even realize he had that in the first place. 

@csi if you define a local variable inside a controller method, you will not be able to use it in the view. Only instance variables (variables with an `@` sign) get passed to the view. Since I agree with Josh that the logic shouldn't be in the controller anyway, his new example shows putting it in the model and then calling it from the view like and that's one option. As we both said, putting it in a view helper is another option if it's truly just formatting and not application logic.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can can add `half_off` and `quarter_off` as methods to your model:

```
class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
  def half_off
    orig_price * 0.5
  end

  def quarter_off
    orig_price * 0.25
  end
end
```

.. and then do the following:

```
def show
  @discount = Discount.find(params[:id])
end
```

Now you can call `@discount.half_off` and `@discount.quarter_off` in your view..

Answer (score 1):

First off, you've got some syntax issues there. When you define methods you need to use a `def` keyword, and since Ruby 1.9 you can use a shortcut when defining hashes that avoids hashrockets, so it's:

```
def calc_discounts
    half_off = @discount.orig_price * .5  
    quarter_off = @discount.orig_price * .25  
    return {half: half_off, quarter: quarter_off}  
end
```

Also, you defined a local variable `formatter` inside of your controller's `show` method. This doesn't actually do anything but assign some values to a variable that only exists within that method. Only the controller's instance variables (variables with an `@`) can be passed to the view.

That being said, the best practice in RoR is to keep controllers "skinny", which means only using controllers to authenticate, authorize, load a model, assign an instance variable for you view, handle errors with any of the former, and then render the view according to the format requested.

It's another best practice not to include much logic in your views. This way, your logic can be shared with and reused by other views instead of having to be re-written for each new view you make. It also makes your views more readable, as they will read like simple lists of what is to be shown instead of making people try to decipher embedded ruby all over the place.

If the code is something that one of your other models could benefit from being able to use, put it inside your model code (or make a new plain old Ruby object if the logic is complex or not really cohesive with the existing model).

If the logic is something that is just for making a view prettier or in a better format, but won't actually be used by the models, then it should go in some type of [view helper](http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-view-helpers-in-rails-4) or [decorator](http://johnotander.com/rails/2014/03/07/decorators-on-rails/).